# Import JSON object in VueJS and add new items to it

Tags: php, json, vue.js

In VueJS, i'm importing some JSON from a server.
After this I'm displaying the data with a v-for directive.

The thing is, at a later moment, I want to add extra data to that JSON object.

This is an example of the dataobject generator by PHP:

```
{
"Height": {
    "description": "Height of product in centimeters.",
    "values": {
        "1": {
            "value": "20cm",
            "extra": ""
        },
        "2": {
            "value": "60cm",
            "extra": ""
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my VueJS instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#attributes_list',
  data: {
    attributes: {!! $attributes_json !!}
  },

  methods: {
    addAttribute : function(attr) {
      this.attributes[attr].values.new = {value: 'test', extra: 'test2'};
    }

  }
})
```

And the button with the event:

```
<button @click.prevent="addAttribute('Height')">Add</button>
```

I already know it doesn't work because of the values are not in an array, so I can't push new data into it. But how to I add new data to this object though?

At the server side, I can't change format the data is put out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `$set` method of vue,

```
this.$set('attributes.' + attr + '.values.new', {value: 'test', extra: 'test2'})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f7pdf9nx/

Comment: Thanks for answer! For others, you might need to put bracket "[]" around the attr. like this `.$set('attributes.["' + attr + '"]', data)`, in case the dot syntax throwing invalid setter expression.